# Winrar command line compression ratio

Tags: command-line, compression, winrar

I have a Winrar command line that look like this:

```
"c:\Program Files\WinRAR\WinRAR.exe" a -afrar -s -m5 "e:\output.rar" "e:\foldertozip"
```

The folder that I am compress by default is 9.08MB. The compression file output is 7.62MB. But if I try to right click the folder and select `Add to "foldertozip.rar"`, the compressed file size is 1.35MB.

How can I achieve that high compression ratio with command line?

Comment: Strange. Try to search where is the different behaviour cause. Some obvious specification: Do the 2 rar archive include the same files inside? (this because eventual setting to avoid hidden files/directories). If you compress again the 7.62 MB file renaming it and using the _right click_, will it shrink to something close to 1.35? Did you try to avoid the `-s` switch or the `-m5`?  Good hunting.

Comment: @Hastur Yes, I tried to avoid both `-s` and `-m5`. Having `-m5` or not does nothing different. But without `-s`, the file size is a bit larger. That is 8.1MB. The strange thing is I only get 1.35MB when compress with `Add to "foldertozip.rar"`. If I choose `Add to archive...`, no matter how I set, the output is 7-8MB. What setting is `Add to "foldertozip.rar"` using?

Comment: It should be possible to check it. Try to see  in the _option-settings_ and maybe in the _advanced_ panel too. You can read [the manual here](http://acritum.com/software/manuals/winrar/html/helpcompressionadvanced.htm): maybe it can be related with _Dictionary size_ and _Memory to use_  or less commonly with _delta compression_ options in the command line default settings vs your actual profile GUI ones.

Answer (score 1):

Use rar.exe instead of winrar.exe with -m5 parameter (max compression).

Comment: It appear error `ERROR: Unknown option: afrar`

Comment: There is no afrar option for rar.exe. Run rar /? to see all valid options.